# Trasversing the values in java

Tags: java

I want to make the statement loop, and I had done it by using the while statement. However, I also want to know wether I can loop the "println" statement by using for loops in the ArrayList instead of the while statement? I want to repeat it fror
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighestGradeTester {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Enter a grade (between 0 and 100) : ");
    int greatest = -1;
    int i = 5;
        while(scores.size()<5){
        
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        if(input <= 100 && input >= 0){
            scores.add(input);
            if(input >= greatest)
                greatest = input;
            i--;
            if(i != 0)
                System.out.println("Enter "+i+" more grades.");
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println("\nHighest grade: "+greatest);
    
}
}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code. Right now it's somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Every `while` loop can be transformed into a `for` loop. But you should not do that.
`for` loops suggest / hint at a fixed number of iterations, which is not the case here.

A `while` loop fits better, keep it like it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert **while** loop into **for** loop and also you can loop the print statements using **for**.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println("Enter a grade (between 0 and 100) : ");
int greatest = -1;

    for(int i=5;scores.size()<5;i--){
    
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    if(input <= 100 && input >= 0){
        scores.add(input);
        if(input >= greatest)
            greatest = input;
        if(i-1 != 0)
            System.out.println("Enter "+(i-1)+" more grades.");
    }
    
}
System.out.println("\nHighest grade: "+greatest);
```